# Curvatura de texto igual al path d3.js sunburts

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Tengo un grafico Sunburts con d3.js y quiero que el texto acompañe la curva del path que esta en el mismo elemento g que lo contiene pero recién empiezo con el uso de la librería **d3.js** y no encuentro documentación clara acerca de la misma.
dejo el codepen donde esta el código.

```js
// Define el JSON con el elemento raíz TOPICS que tiene un tamaño (size) adecuado
  const jsonData = {
  "name": "Nelson Barolin",
  "children": [{
    "name": "Elbio Barolin",
    "size": 1,
    "text": "A story",
    "sentiment": 0.8,
    "source": "dictionary",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Jean Barolin",
        "size": 500,
        "text": "",
        "sentiment": 0,
        "source": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Etienne B.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Sussane A.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Maria Negrin",
        "size": 500,
        "text": "",
        "sentiment": 0,
        "source": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Joshep N.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Madeleine B.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "María Marta",
    "size": 1,
    "text": "A note",
    "sentiment": 0.3,
    "source": "dictionary",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Philip Gardiol",
        "size": 500,
        "text": "",
        "sentiment": 0,
        "source": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Philip Sr.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Marta P.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Ana Baridon",
        "size": 500,
        "text": "",
        "sentiment": 0,
        "source": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Jean B.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Anne D.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "Marta Maeso",
    "size": 1,
    "text": "A vignette",
    "sentiment": 0.5,
    "source": "newspaper",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Jos Maeso",
        "size": 500,
        "text": "",
        "sentiment": 0,
        "source": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Maeso",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Rivas",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Josefa Panario",
        "size": 500,
        "text": "",
        "sentiment": 0,
        "source": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Domingo P.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Juana B.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "name": "aida Canepa",
    "size": 1,
    "text": "A tall-tale",
    "sentiment": 0.2,
    "source": "friend",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Jose Canepa",
        "size": 500,
        "text": "",
        "sentiment": 0,
        "source": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Antonio C.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Juana A.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Maria Luzardo",
        "size": 500,
        "text": "",
        "sentiment": 0,
        "source": "",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Jose L.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          },
          {
            "name": "Maria G.",
            "size": 50000,
            "text": "",
            "sentiment": 0,
            "source": "",
            "children": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }]
};





    // Variables
    var width = 500;
    var height = 500;
    var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);
    // Cambia el tamaño de nuestro elemento <svg>, agrega un elemento <g> y mueve la traducción 0,0 al centro del elemento.
    var g = d3.select('svg')
      .attr('width', width)
      .attr('height', height)
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', 'translate(' + width / 2 + ',' + height / 2 + ')');
    // Crear nuestra estructura de datos sunburst y dimensionarla.
    var partition = d3.partition()
      .size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);
    // Encuentre el nodo raíz de nuestros datos y comience el proceso de dimensionamiento.
    var root = d3.hierarchy(jsonData)
      .sum(function(d) {
        return d.size;
      });
    // Calculate the sizes of each arc that we'll draw later.
    partition(root);
    var arc = d3.arc()
      .startAngle(function(d) {
        return d.x0;
      })
      .endAngle(function(d) {
        return d.x1;
      })
      .innerRadius(function(d) {
        return d.y0;
      })
      .outerRadius(function(d) {
        return d.y1;
      });
    // Agregue un elemento <g> para cada nodo en los datos, luego agregue elementos <ruta> y dibuje líneas basadas en el arco
     // cálculos de variables. Por último, colorea las líneas y los cortes.
    var nodes = g.selectAll('g')
  .data(root.descendants())
  .enter().append('g')
  .attr("class", function(d) {
    // Asignar una clase basada en la profundidad (generación) del nodo
    var generation = "GEN_" + d.depth;
    return d.parent ? generation : generation + " root-node";
  });
    nodes.append('path')
      .attr("display", function(d) {
        return d.depth ? null : "none";
      })
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style('stroke', '#fff')
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name);
      });

  var defs = g.append("defs");

    //  elementos <text>
      nodes.append("text")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")rotate(" + computeTextRotation(d) + ")";
      })
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
      .text(function(d) {
        return d.parent ? d.data.name : "";
      });
    // Agregar etiqueta de texto para el nodo raíz
    g.append("text")
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
      .text(jsonData.name);
    /**
      * Calcular la distancia correcta para rotar cada etiqueta en función de su ubicación en el resplandor solar.
      * @param {Nodo} d
      * @return {Número}
      */
    function computeTextRotation(d) {
      var angle = (d.x0 + d.x1) / Math.PI * 90;
      // Avoid upside-down labels
      return (angle < 90 || angle > 270) ? angle : angle + 180; 
    }
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
body{
  background: #3f3f3f;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sunburst2</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <svg></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: los textos curvados en D3 son conocidos por ser difíciles de implementar, especialmente en un diagrama de sunburst, debido a las complejidades de calcular la rotación y orientación correcta del texto para que siga la curva de los segmentos del diagrama.
Fijate acá:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10144963/how-to-put-text-along-a-circle-or-arc-with-d3-js

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIONADO!!

Adiciónamos un path que es calculado por la función middleArcLine() y cada uno con un id distinto para linkearlo al textpath.

```javascript
nodes
  .append("path")
  .attr("class", "hidden-arc") // ocultamos el path
  .attr("id", (_, i) => `hiddenArc${i}`) // asignamos un id
  .attr("fill", "none") // sin relleno
  .attr("d", middleArcLine); // el path es creado para que el texto se adapte justo a la mitad , también si el texto está de cabeza se invierte el mismo
```

Luego se agrega el texto y el textpath

```javascript
nodes
      .append("text")
      .attr("dx", function(d) { return  CalcDx(d.depth) })
      .append("textPath")
      .attr('xlink:href', (_, i) => `#hiddenArc${i}`) // Vinculamos el texto al arco correspondiente
      .text(function (d) {
        return d.parent ? d.data.name : "";
      });
```

muchas gracias!

```js
// Define el JSON con el elemento raíz TOPICS que tiene un tamaño (size) adecuado
const jsonData = {
    name: "Nelson Barolin",
        children: [
            {
                name: "Elbio Barolin",
                size: 1,
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "Enrique Barolin",
                        size: 500,
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: "Jean Barolin",
                                size: 100000,
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: "Etienne Barolin",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "Susanne A.",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Maria Negrin",
                                size: 100000,
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: "Joshep Negrin",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "Madeleine B.",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Maria G.",
                        size: 500,
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: "Phillip G.",
                                size: 100000,
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: "Phillip G. SR",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "Marthe Pastre",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Anna Baridon",
                                size: 100000,
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: "Jean Baridon",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "Anne Davit",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    } // objeto Maria G.
                ]
            } // Objeto Elbio
            ,
            {
                name: "Marta Maeso",
                size: 1,
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "Emilio Maeso",
                        size: 500,
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: "Jose Maeso",
                                size: 100000,
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: "Maeso",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "Rivas",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Josefa P.",
                                size: 100000,
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: "Domingo P.",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "Juana B.",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        name: "Aida Canepa",
                        size: 500,
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: "Jose Canepa",
                                size: 100000,
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: "Antonio C.",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "Juana Alderiz",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    }
                                ]
                            },
                            {
                                name: "Maria Luxardo",
                                size: 100000,
                                children: [
                                    {
                                        name: "Jose Luxardo",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        name: "Maria Gualco",
                                        size: 10000000,
                                        children: []
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    } // objeto Maria G.
                ]
            } // Objeto Elbio
        ] // children main
};

// Variables
var width = 500;
var height = 500;
var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20b);
// Cambia el tamaño de nuestro elemento <svg>, agrega un elemento <g> y mueve la traducción 0,0 al centro del elemento.
var g = d3
  .select("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")");
// Crear nuestra estructura de datos sunburst y dimensionarla.
var partition = d3.partition().size([2 * Math.PI, radius]);
// Encuentre el nodo raíz de nuestros datos y comience el proceso de dimensionamiento.
var root = d3.hierarchy(jsonData).sum(function (d) {
  return d.size;
});
// Calcular los tamaños de cada arco que dibujaremos más tarde.
partition(root);
var arc = d3
  .arc()
  .startAngle(function (d) {
    return d.x0;
  })
  .endAngle(function (d) {
    return d.x1;
  })
  .innerRadius(function (d) {
    return d.y0;
  })
  .outerRadius(function (d) {
    return d.y1;
  });
const middleArcLine = d => {
  const halfPi = Math.PI / 2;
  const angles = [d.x0 - halfPi, d.x1 - halfPi];
  const r = Math.max(0, (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2);

  const middleAngle = (angles[1] + angles[0]) / 2;
  const invertDirection = middleAngle > 0 && middleAngle < Math.PI; // En los cuadrantes inferiores escribir texto ccw
  
  if (invertDirection) { angles.reverse();}

  const path = d3.path();
  path.arc(0, 0, r, angles[0], angles[1], invertDirection);
  return path.toString();
};
// Agregue un elemento <g> para cada nodo en los datos, luego agregue elementos <ruta> y dibuje líneas basadas en el arco
// cálculos de variables. Por último, colorea las líneas y los cortes.
var nodes = g
  .selectAll("g")
  .data(root.descendants())
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", function (d) {
    // Asignar una clase basada en la profundidad (generación) del nodo
    var generation = "GEN_" + d.depth;
    return d.parent ? generation : generation + " root-node";
  });
var arcs = nodes
  .append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("stroke", "#fff")
  .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).data.name);
  });

nodes.append('path') 
  .attr('class', 'hidden-arc')
  .attr('id', (_, i) => `hiddenArc${i}`)
  .attr('fill','none')
  .attr('d', middleArcLine);
//  elementos <text>
nodes
  .append("text")
  .attr("dx", function(d) { return  CalcDx(d.depth) })
  .append("textPath")
  .attr('xlink:href', (_, i) => `#hiddenArc${i}`) // Vinculamos el texto al arco correspondiente
  .text(function (d) {
    return d.parent ? d.data.name : "";
  });

// Agregar etiqueta de texto para el nodo raíz
g.append("text")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("dominant-baseline", "middle")
  .text(jsonData.name);
/**
 * Calcular la distancia correcta para rotar cada etiqueta en función de su ubicación en el resplandor solar.
 * @param {Nodo} d
 * @return {Número}
 */

function CalcDx(gen){
  if(gen === 1){return 70;}
  if(gen === 2){return 50;}
  if(gen === 3){return 15;}
  if(gen === 4){return 5; }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
body{
  background: #3f3f3f;
  font-family: "Raleway", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Sunburst2</title>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <svg></svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).